# Could we have Polymorphism without forcing classes to implement an interface?

Tags: java, oop, language-design

Assume that we have an `interface` called `Animal` that have two methods called `move()` and `makeSound()`.

This means we can send the messages `move()` and `makeSound()` on a variable of type `Animal`, and we can only assign objects of classes that implement `Animal` to a variable of type `Animal`.

Now my question is, could Java have not forced classes that want to use Polymorphism to implement an `interface`?

For example, why didn't Java implement Polymorphism like the following:

We would just create an `Animal` `interface` and then we would be able to assign whatever object we want to a variable of type `Animal` as long as that object have the methods `move()` and `makeSound()`, for example:

```
Animal animal1;

/* The Java compiler will check if Dog have the methods move() and makeSound(), if yes then 
   compile, if no then show a compilation error */
animal1 = new Dog(); 

animal1.move();
animal1.makeSound();
```

Note: I took Java as an example, but I am talking in general about all OOP languages. Also, I know that we can have Polymorphism using a subclass that inherits from a superclass (but this is basically the same idea as using an `interface`).

Comment: So, all you want is to have the advantage of implementing an interface without using the magic words "implements Animal" on the class declaration? I like having this spelled out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is polymorphism possible without inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732422/is-polymorphism-possible-without-inheritance)

Comment: Also semi-related: [Can inheritance be replaced completely by composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108601/1371329)

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of different ways to get polymorphism.  The one you are most familiar with is *inclusion polymorphism* (also known as subtype polymorphism), where the programmer explicitly says "X is-a Y" via some sort of extends clause.  You see this in Java and C#; both give you the choice of having such an is-a for both representation and API (`extends`), or only for API (`implements`).

There is also *parametric polymorphism*, which you have probably seen as generics: defining a family of types `Foo<T>` with a single declaration.  You see this in Java/C#/Scala (generics), C++ (templates), Haskell (type classes), etc.

Some languages have "duck typing", where, rather than looking at the declaration ("X is-a Y"), they are willing to determine typing structurally.  If a contract says "to be an `Iterator`, you have to have `hasNext()` and `next()` methods", then under this interpretation, any class that provides these two methods is an `Iterator`, regardless of whether it said so or not.  This comports with the case you describe; this was a choice open to the Java designers.

Languages with pattern matching or runtime reflection can exhibit a form of *ad-hoc polymorphism* (also known as data-driven polymorphism), where you can define polymorphic behavior over unrelated types, such as:

```
int length(Object o) {
    return switch (o) {
        case String s -> s.length();
        case Object[] os -> os.length;
        case Collection c -> c.size();
        ...
    };
}
```

Here, `length` is polymorphic over an ad-hoc set of types.

It is also possible to have an explicit declaration of "X is-a Y" without putting this *in the declaration of X*.  Haskell's type classes do this, where, rather than X declaring "I'm a Y", there's a separate declaration of an `instance` that explicitly says "X is a Y (and here is how to map X functionality to Y functionality if it is not obvious to the compiler.)"  Such instances are often called *witnesses*; it is a witness to the Y-hood of X.  Clojure's protocols are similar, and Scala's implicit parameters play a similar role ("find me a witness to `CanCopyFrom[A,B]`, or fail at compile time").

The point of all this is that there are many ways to get polymorphism, and some languages pick their favorite, others support more than one, etc.

If your question is *why* did Java choose explicit subtyping rather than duck typing, the answer is fairly clear: Java was a language designed for building large systems (as was C++) out of components, and components want strong checking at their boundaries.  A loosey-goosey match because the two sides happen to have methods with the same name is a less reliable means of establishing programmer intent than an explicit declaration.  Additionally, one of the core design principles of the Java language is "reading code is more important than writing code."  It may be more work to declare "implements Iterator" (but not a lot more), but it makes it much more clear to readers what your design intent was.

So, this is a tradeoff of what we might now call "ceremony" for greater reliability and more clear capture of design intent.

Answer (score 4):

The approach you're describing is called "[structural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) subtyping", and it is not only possible, but actually in use; for example, it is used by [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(programming_language)) and [TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript).

Per the *Go Programming Language Specification*:

> A variable of interface type can store a value of any type with a method set that is any superset of the interface. […]
>
> A type implements any interface comprising any subset of its methods and may therefore implement several distinct interfaces. For instance, all types implement the empty interface:
>
> ```
> interface{}
> ```
>
> [[link](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)]

Per the TypeScript documentation:

> Type compatibility in TypeScript is based on structural subtyping. Structural typing is a way of relating types based solely on their members. This is in contrast with nominal typing. Consider the following code:
>
> ```
> interface Named {
>     name: string;
> }
>
> class Person {
>     name: string;
> }
>
> let p: Named;
> // OK, because of structural typing
> p = new Person();
> ```
>
> In nominally-typed languages like C# or Java, the equivalent code would be an error because the `Person` class does not explicitly describe itself as being an implementer of the `Named` interface.
>
> [[link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)]

---

> Note: I took Java as an example, but I am talking in general about all OOP languages.

I'm not sure it's possible to talk "in general about all OOP languages", because there are so many, and they work in many different ways. Your question makes sense for Java, but it wouldn't make sense for Go or TypeScript (since as you see, it has exactly the feature you'd be claiming it doesn't), nor for non-statically-typed OO as in Python or JavaScript (since they don't have the notion of "a variable of type `Animal`").

---

**ETA:** In a follow-up comment, you write:

> Since it was possible for Java to not force classes to [explicitly] implement an `interface`, then why did Java force classes to [explicitly] implement an `interface`?

I can't say for certain; the first edition of the *Java Language Specification* [[link](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jls1-spec/)] explicitly called this out, but didn't indicate the rationale:

> It  is  not  sufficient  that  the  class  happen  to  implement  all  the abstract methods of the interface; the class or one of its superclasses must actually be declared to implement the interface, or else the class is not considered to implement the interface. [p. 183]

However, I think the main reason was probably that interfaces are intended to have a *meaning*, which often goes beyond what's explicitly indicated in the method signatures. For example:

- `java.util.List`, in addition to specifying various methods of its own, also specifies the behavior of `equals` and `hashCode`, instructing implementations to override the implementations provided by `java.lang.Object` and implement the specified behavior. If it were possible to "accidentally" implement `java.util.List`, then that instruction would be meaningless, because implementations might not even "know" that they were implementations.
- `java.io.Serializable` has no methods at all; it's just a "marker" interface to tell the Java Serialization API that this class is OK with being serialized and deserialized. In Go, such an interface would be meaningless, because every type would automatically implement it.

Some other (IMHO less-significant) possible reasons:

- Java method signatures are a bit more complicated than Go method signatures, in that they can also declare exceptions, and in that Java allows method overloading (multiple methods with the same name but different signatures). These features make it more likely that a class accidentally fails to implement an interface it's supposed to. When that happens, Java's current approach means that you get a single error-message in the place where you define the class, instead of hundreds of error-messages throughout your program in every place where you've written `Animal animal = new Cat()`.
- Interfaces are allowed to have static fields, which classes inherit (rather than needing to implement). I'm not sure how this would work if classes didn't explicitly indicate which interfaces they implement.
- The current approach allows the subtyping relationship to be determined completely at compile-time; by contrast, if something like `Animal animal = (Animal) obj;` or `if (obj instanceof Animal)` were allowed, then the runtime would need to analyze `obj`'s runtime-type on the fly to determine if it conforms to the `Animal` interface. (This also means that adding a method to the `Animal` interface could potentially cause runtime failures rather than compile-time failures.)
- Even just within the compiler, the current approach may simplify some things by letting the compiler verify in one place that the class satisfies the interface, and then just use that fact everywhere that an implicit or explicit conversion appears. (This is related to my comment above about clearer error-messages.)

. . . but, again, this is just me speculating. I think I'm probably in the right ballpark, but a lot of things go into language design, and there could easily have been major considerations that would never occur to me.

Comment: Its also working in Smalltalk on Objective-C, which have that 'sending message to an object and see if it understands it' approach, where as in Java a method call is a method call.

Comment: @Ridcully: Neither Smalltalk nor Objective-C has "interfaces"; rather, they use [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), like Python and JavaScript.

Comment: Since it was possible for Java to not force classes to implement an `interface`, then why did Java force classes to implement an `interface`? is it because it makes the code easier to read (i.e. it becomes easier to see which classes are using Polymorphism)?

Comment: @Tom : what do you mean by "Java force classes to implement interface" ? There are some patern that are based on this kind of coercive behavior like the Dependency Injection (like in spring framework) ... but this a just a highly recommended patern for some use case. Anybody "force" interface implementation...you can write classes without any interface implementation

Comment: @Tom : interfaces are here to help code scalability and maintenance. This just an abstraction layer, This could help you for example to change implementation between classes. But you can write a whole program, without any interface....this is totally up to you (it is still considered as a best practice to write code with abstraction, this is one of the OOP principle and interfaces helps you to achieve this, but you can also write procedural code without any kind of interface)

Comment: @Tom :  I also updated my answer to include this explanation (with a reference to a very good code example on the Dependency Injection DP which will help you for sure to better understand the meaning of Interface in Java) Let me know if something not clear

Comment: @yossefaz By  "Java force classes to implement interface", I meant that a class have to do something like this when wanting to use an interface: `class Cat implements Animal` (and then you have to write methods implementations in `Cat` for the methods definitions that exist in the `Animal` interface), while in Golang for example, in order for the `Cat` class to use the `Animal` interface, you have to **only** write method implementations in `Cat` for the methods definitions that exist in the `Animal` interface.

Comment: @Tom: I've appended a section to this answer to address that.

Comment: @Tom : okay. We could understand your question in the both ways. But I also answers an gave you an example of golang implementation in my answer.  Of course in Java you will have to explicitly implements the interface, the language is designed in this way

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this behavior is implemented with a [structural type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system). As expressed in a [different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62907617/2398375), Go is one language which support structural typing.

By checking the [language comparison by type system wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_by_type_system), you can find other languages which support a structural type system.

---

Java uses a [nominal type system](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system), which requires types to be explicitly defined.

Asking why Java uses a nominal type system would be like asking why is statically typed. **There are pros and cons to both**, and language developers choose which strategies fit the philosophy of the language.